# What do you call the "collars" of a bathrobe?

Tags: word-request, terminology

In other words, what do you call these?

[image]

(Each individual side?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most generically, they would be called [**lapels**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapel) (the left lapel and the right lapel). And, to the best of my knowledge, it's absolutely irrelevant whether it's a coat or a bathrobe that you're talking about—they're still called lapels. There are different types of lapels such as notch lapels, peak lapels and so on and so forth, but they're all lapels.

Answer (score 7):

That entire feature inside your circle is sometimes called a **shawl collar**.  If you were shopping for such a garment, you would tell the salesperson that you wanted a bathrobe "with a shawl collar".

Comment: It's just a collar usually. And when uses, usually applies to sweaters. Most bathrobes have them anyway.

Comment: @Lambie Relevance of "most bahtrobes have them"?

Comment: I don't have that typo on my screen. But I do want to correct uses to used.

Comment: @Lambie Clever dodge.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd call it a **collar**, but I've never sewed anything in my life.

According to the people at **[Fabrics-store.com](https://blog.fabrics-store.com/2015/06/29/linen-bathrobe-tutorial/)**, who *have* sewn, it's called a **collar panel**.

[image: pattern for robe]

Image text:

> Along the slanted edge, press 3/8 inch (1cm) of the seam allowance towards the wrong side of the
> collar panel.
>
> Pin the pressed edge of the collar panel along the front and back bodice panel. Sandwich the bodice seam inbetween the collar panel. Make sure the notched back centre mark matches with the stitched collar panel seams.
> Stitch along the pinned seam.

---

I also just learned that [***sewed*** and ***sewn***](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sewn%20vs%20sewed) are interchangeable!

Comment: This is only the sewing te3rm. Not a descriptive one.